# Statement about limits superior

Tags: real-analysis

> > For $i=1,\ldots,k$ let $(a_n^{(i)})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers. Then
> >     $$
> > \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(a_n^{(1)}+\ldots+a_n^{(k)})=\max_{1\leq i\leq k}\left\{\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log a_n^{(i)}\right\}.
> > $$

I have some problems to understand the following proof.

"$\le$" is clear since for every $i\in\left\{1,...,k\right\}$ we have $a_n^{(1)}+...+a_n^{(k)}\geq a_n^{(i)}$ and hence the left-hand side of the equality is greater than or equal the right-hand side.

But "$\geq$" males me some problems:

Let $R$ denote the right-hand side of the equality. If $R=\infty$, then there remains nothing to show. If $R$ is finite, then for every $i\in\left\{1,...,k\right\}$ one has $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log a_n^{(i)}\leq R$.

> > So if $\varepsilon >0$, then
> >     $$
> > a_n^{(i)}\leq\exp(n(R+\varepsilon))~\text{ for almost all }n.~~~~~(*)
> > $$
> >     Consequently,
> >     $$
> > a_n^{(1)}+...+a_n^{(k)}\leq n\cdot\exp(n(R+\varepsilon)).~~~~(**)
> > $$
> >     It follows that
> >     $$
> > \frac{1}{n}\log(a_n^{(1)}+...+a_n^{(k)})\leq \frac{1}{n}\log n+R+\varepsilon~\text{for almost all }n.~~~(***)
> > $$
> >     Thus, the left-hand side of the equality above is less than or equal to $R+\varepsilon$. Since this holds for every $\varepsilon >0$, the desired result follows.

I do not understand the statements $(*)$, $(**)$ and $(***)$, especially the "for almost all n".

Could you pls explain them to me?

Comment: No problem, typos happen all the time.

Comment: I really have no idea how to see the three statements, espcecially $(*)$.

Comment: ok about $(*)$ its from definition of limit, there are infinitly many points in interval $(R - \varepsilon , R + \varepsilon )$ , and R is biggest such point (since its lim sup) meaning there can be only finite number of points bigger then $R + \varepsilon $   , points are $ \{ 1/n log(a_n^{(i)})\}_{n \in N}$ you get rest from (*) just sum them for all i, and do log or exp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "for almost all $n$" means "there is an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geqslant N$". A property holds "for almost all $n$" if it holds for all but finitely many $n$, so it holds for all "sufficiently large" $n$.

Here, by definition of $\limsup$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is, for every $i$ an $N_i(\varepsilon)$ such that

$$\frac{1}{m}\log a_m^{(i)} < \varepsilon + \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log a_n^{(i)}\tag{1}$$

holds for all $m \geqslant N_i(\varepsilon)$. By definition of $R$, we thus have

$$\frac{1}{m}\log a_m^{(i)} < R + \varepsilon\tag{2}$$

for $m \geqslant N_i(\varepsilon)$. Let $N(\varepsilon) = \max\limits_{1\leqslant i \leqslant k} N_i(\varepsilon)$. Then for $m \geqslant N(\varepsilon)$, the inequality $(2)$ holds for all $i$. And thus, by multiplication and exponentiation we reach

$$n \geqslant N(\varepsilon) \implies a_n^{(i)} < \exp\bigl(n\cdot (R+\varepsilon)\bigr)\tag{$\ast$}$$

for $1 \leqslant i \leqslant k$. Summing the inequalities $(\ast)$ for $1 \leqslant i \leqslant k$, we obtain

$$n\geqslant N(\varepsilon) \implies a_n^{(1)} + \dotsc + a_n^{(k)} < k\cdot \exp\bigl(n(R+\varepsilon)\bigr).\tag{$\ast\!\ast$}$$

In your question, the factor in front of the exponential is $n$ rather than $k$. For $n > k$, that is a weaker inequality, hence implied by $(\ast\ast)$ here. For $n < k$, it might be wrong, but since we are interested in the behaviour as $n \to \infty$ and can always choose $N(\varepsilon) \geqslant k$, that's not something to worry about. However, it is conceptually irritating to choose a factor of $n$ there rather than the fixed $k$, since on the left hand side we have a sum of $k$ terms, each bounded above by the same expression. Hence it is more natural to let the right hand side be $k$ times the bound for each of the terms.

Now, taking logarithms in $(\ast\ast)$, where we denote the factor by $F$, which could be either of $k$ or $n$ [for sufficiently large $n$], we obtain

$$\log \bigl(a_n^{(1)} + \dotsc + a_n^{(k)}\bigr) < n(R+\varepsilon) + \log F.$$

Then we can divide by $n$ to obtain

$$\frac{1}{n}\log \bigl(a_n^{(1)} + \dotsc + a_n^{(k)}\bigr) < R + \varepsilon + \frac{\log F}{n} \tag{$\ast\!\ast\!\ast$}$$

for all $n \geqslant N(\varepsilon)$. Since $\frac{\log F}{n} \to 0$, that shows

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\log \bigl(a_n^{(1)} + \dotsc + a_n^{(k)}\bigr) \leqslant R + \varepsilon.$$

Since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary,

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\log \bigl(a_n^{(1)} + \dotsc + a_n^{(k)}\bigr) \leqslant R$$

follows.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I do not see how (1) follows.

Comment: What do you know about $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n$ in general, when $(b_n)$ is a real sequence?

Comment: It is defined to be $\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n:=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sup_{k\geq n}b_k)$.

Comment: So, given $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $\sup_{k \geqslant m} b_k < \varepsilon + \limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n$ for all large enough $m$, right?

Comment: I do not see that...

Comment: Let $c_n = \sup_{k \geqslant n} b_k$. By definition, $\limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} c_n$. Now, if $L = \lim c_n$, then, given $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an $N$ such that $\lvert c_n - L\rvert < \varepsilon$ for $n \geqslant N$. But $\lvert c_n - L\rvert <\varepsilon$ means $L - \varepsilon < c_n < L + \varepsilon$. We need only the inequality $c_n < L+\varepsilon$ for $n \geqslant N$. Now insert the definition of $c_n$: $$\sup_{k \geqslant n} b_k < L + \varepsilon$$ for $n\geqslant N$. And hence, we have $b_k < L +\varepsilon$ for $k \geqslant N$.

Comment: Is it correct to say that for $i\in\left\{1,...,k\right\}$, we have  $\frac{1}{n}\log a_n^{(i)}\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log a_n^{(i)}$ for almost all $n$? Doesn't this follow by (1), when letting $\varepsilon\to 0$? But I guess it does not make any sense to let $\varepsilon\to 0$ already in (1).

Comment: No, that need not be the case. If for example you have a strictly decreasing sequence, every term is larger than the $\limsup$. And generally, there can be infinitely many terms in the sequence larger. You need the buffer $\varepsilon > 0$ to get the inequality, and then you let $\varepsilon \to 0$ at the end.

Comment: Ok, but why is it okay to let $\varepsilon\to 0$ at the end? Why is it then no problem?

Comment: At the end, we have eliminated the dependence on $n$. We have an inequality $L < R + \varepsilon$, where $L$ and $R$ are fixed real numbers. And we have that inequality for _all_ $\varepsilon > 0$. Before that, we have a dependence on two variables, $\varepsilon$ and $n$. Since $n$ (rather, the range of admissible $n$) depends on $\varepsilon$, these are not independent, and since [the admissible range of] $n$ depends on $\varepsilon$, we have to eliminate $n$ first.

Comment: Then in (2) it should be okay to let $\varepsilon\to 0$, i.e. the statement $\frac{1}{m}\log a_m^{(i)}\leq R$ should be okay for almost all $m$?

Comment: Ah, no... since again this depends on $m$.